# Roots of a $5$th degree polynomial are $\tan A, \tan B, \ldots, \tan E$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\tan A$, $\tan B$, $\tan C$, $\tan D$, and $\tan E$ are the roots of the equation $x^5-3x^4-4x^2+3x-5=0$, find the sum of all principal values of $A+B+C+D+E$.

What do I do with that equation? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could include your work so far on the problem?

Comment: I tried finding a root. No rational exists. Then on wolfram alpha, one real and 4 complex...

Comment: Hint: derive a formula for $\tan(a+b+c+d+e)$ and use Viete's theorem.

Comment: @You-know-me: can I ask where you found this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: let $s_1$ through $s_5$ denote the elementary symmetric polynomials in 5 variables. Set $x_1=\tan A$, $x_2=\tan B$, etc, and try to prove

$$\tan\left(A+B+C+D+E\right)=\frac{s_1(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)-s_3(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)+s_5(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)}{1-s_2(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)+s_4(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)}$$

Then use Vieta's formulas.